# socket.io - Client socket time out

Tags: socket.io, timeout

Socket.io has connection and disconnect events.

Does socket.io has timeout event for client sockets, that are already connected?

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

Comment: I think everything is spelled out here [javascript + socket.io Change timeout value option client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390268/javascript-socket-io-change-timeout-value-option-client-side/32393490#32393490).  It isn't as simple as you might think.

Comment: I am trying to see timeout after socket connected. Like, in case if power goes, then client socket does not sent disconnect  event. How can I identify that socket is no longer exist.

Comment: socket.io uses a ping/pong scheme to regularly send packets between client and server.  If that regular set of transmissions is interrupted, then either client or server will know that the other end is no longer connected.  This behavior is built in to socket.io already.

Comment: Ok, But i want to perform some action on this transmissions, how to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?